# Working with Laravel and AJAX - Not loading DIV

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-4

I'm really puzzled by this. I have no errors in apache logs or in my browser (chrome).

I can visit this particular page (localhost/admin/networks) and click on an item from a database generated list. When clicked the item will open a css popup div that I can add a database entry with. This portion works fine. However, I also have a live search box so you can type in a partial network to see the results. When you click on one of the results though it will bring up the css popup, but it will be empty like its failing to find the file - even though it works just fine pre-search. I had this working at one point, but I added a route prefix and I think my issue lies between my JS file and my route prefixes. I honestly have no idea where to begin checking though as it works until searched.

Also, feel free to criticize. I'm still learning so if I'm doing something in a terrible way feel free to let me know. Any help is appreciated!

**Edit 2:**

I've narrowed it down to the third argument on the .load of my javascript file. I added my route prefixes back in and below is my current js file.

**current js.js file**

```
var baseURL = "https://localhost/";
var admURL = "https://localhost/admin/";
//DIV View Toggle

function toggle(div_id)
{
    var el = document.getElementById(div_id);
    if(el.style.display == 'none')
    {
        el.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else
    {
        el.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
function togglePopBox(windowname)
{    
    toggle('popBox');
    toggle('popBackground');
}
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //Add Networks Button
    $("#addNet").on('click', function()
    {
        $("#popBox").load(admURL + 'addnetwork', setupInternalPopBoxNetworks);
    });

    //Kills popup
    function setupInternalPopBoxNetworks()
    {
        $("#cancelNet").on('click', function()
        {
            $("#popBox").load(baseURL + 'blank', setupInternalPopBoxNetworks);
        });
    }

    //Network Search Function
    $('#searchNetworkID').keyup(function(e){
        $("#networkBox").load(baseURL + 'network.search' + '?networkSearch=' + $('#searchNetworkID').val());
    });

    //Add Subnets Button
    $(".addSubnet").on('click', function()
    {
        var netID = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#popBox").load(admURL + 'addsubnet' + '?network=' + netID, setupInternalPopBoxNetworks);
    });

    //View Subnets Button
    $(".viewSubnet").on('click', function()
    {
        var netID = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#subnetBox").load(baseURL + 'viewsubnet' + '?network=' + netID, setupInternalPopBoxNetworks);
    });

//Subnet Search
    $('#searchSubnetID').keyup(function(e){
        $("#subnetBox").load(baseURL + 'subnet.search' + '?subnetSearch=' + $('#searchSubnetID').val());
    });

});
```

**Edit 1:**

> I removed the route group I defined with the same issue. I reverted
>   back before I had created another popUp DIV on the suspicion that
>   maybe I had created a conflict somewhere. I'm not real sure what it
>   is, but after playing around some more I think there is an issue in my
>   js.js file.
>
> I am pretty sure the issue I'm running into has to do with async since
>   I'm using http://api.jquery.com/load/. I changed my subnets button to
>   the code below and would get a loaded popup, but it would just be the
>   one it loaded previously because the div would not blank out when
>   closed.
>
> I feel I'm getting close, but obviously still missing something major.
>
> ```
> $(".addSubnet").on('click', function()
> {
>     var netID = $(this).attr('id');
>     $("#popBox").load(baseURL + 'addsubnet' + '?network=' + netID);
> });
> ```

**routes.php**

```
#Route Prefix for administration
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    #Network Management Page - Add, Edit, Delete
    Route::get('networks', function()
    {
        $userGroups = implode(',', Auth::user()->groups);
        $userGroups = ''.$userGroups.'';
        $userGroups = explode(",", $userGroups);
        $CanIVisit = Link::whereIn('linkGroup', $userGroups)->count();
        if($CanIVisit > 0){
            return View::make('networks');
        }else{
            return Redirect::intended('landing');
        }
    });

    #Adds a Network
    Route::get('addnetwork', array(
        'as' => 'network.add',
        'uses' => 'NetworksController@add'
    ));

    #POSTS added network data
    Route::post('networks', array('before' => 'csrf', 
        'as' => 'network.create',
        'uses' => 'NetworksController@create'
    ));

    #Adds subnet to specified network
    Route::get('addsubnet', array(
        'as' => 'subnet.add',
        'uses' => 'NetworksController@addSubnet'
    ));

    #POSTS subnet information to database
    Route::post('subnets', array('before' => 'csrf', 
        'as' => 'subnet.create',
        'uses' => 'NetworksController@createSubnet'
    ));
});
```

**NetworksController.php**

```
public function search()
{
$lineNumber = 1;
$network = Input::get('networkSearch');
$networks = IPv4Network::where('easyNet', 'LIKE', "$network%")
    ->orWhere('route', 'LIKE', "$network%")
    ->orderBy('network', 'asc')
    ->get();
$networksCount = IPv4Network::where('easyNet', 'LIKE', "$network%")
    ->orWhere('route', 'LIKE', "$network%")
    ->orderBy('network', 'asc')
    ->count();

if($networksCount == 0){
    echo("No networks matched the criteria entered.");
}else{
    echo("<div id=\"networkListHead\">");
    echo("<div class=\"networkID\">Network</div>");
    echo("<div class=\"networkMask\">Mask</div>");
    echo("<div class=\"networkPath\">Route Path</div>");
    echo("<div class=\"networkSubnets\">Subnets</div>");
    echo("<div class=\"networkHosts\">Hosts</div>");
    echo("<div class=\"networkMaxHosts\">Max Hosts</div>");
    echo("</div>");

    foreach($networks as $foundNet){
        $findSubnets = IPv4Subnets::where('networkID', '=', $foundNet->networkID)
            ->get();
        $findSubnetsCount = IPv4Subnets::where('networkID', '=', $foundNet->networkID)
            ->count();


        $mask = (32 - $foundNet->mask);
        $MaxHosts = (pow(2, $mask) - 2);

        if($lineNumber == 1){
            echo("<div class=\"networkListA\">");
            echo("<div class=\"networkID\"><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"togglePopBox('popBox')\" class=\"addSubnet\" id=\"{$foundNet->networkID}\">".long2ip($foundNet->network)."</a></div>");
            echo("<div class=\"networkMask\">{$foundNet->mask}</div>");
            echo("<div class=\"networkPath\">{$foundNet->route}</div>");
            echo("<div class=\"networkSubnets\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"viewSubnet\" id=\"{$foundNet->networkID}\">{$findSubnetsCount}</a></div>");
            echo("<div class=\"networkHosts\">");
            if($findSubnetsCount == 0){
                echo("0");
            }else{
                $hostCount = IPv4Hosts::all()
                    ->count();

                if($hostCount == 0){
                    echo("0");
                }else{
                    echo $hostCount;
                }
            }
            echo("</div>");
            echo("<div class=\"networkMaxHosts\">");
            echo $MaxHosts;
            echo("</div>");
            echo("</div>");
            $lineNumber = 2;
        }else{
            echo("<div class=\"networkListB\">");
            echo("<div class=\"networkID\"><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"togglePopBox('popBox')\" class=\"addSubnet\" id=\"{$foundNet->networkID}\">".long2ip($foundNet->network)."</a></div>");
            echo("<div class=\"networkMask\">{$foundNet->mask}</div>");
            echo("<div class=\"networkPath\">{$foundNet->route}</div>");
            echo("<div class=\"networkSubnets\"><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"togglePopBox('popBox')\" class=\"viewSubnet\" id=\"{$foundNet->networkID}\">{$findSubnetsCount}</a></div>");
            echo("<div class=\"networkHosts\">");
            if($findSubnetsCount == 0){
                echo("0");
            }else{
                $hostCount = IPv4Hosts::all()
                    ->count();

                if($hostCount == 0){
                    echo("0");
                }else{
                    echo $hostCount;
                }
            }
            echo("</div>");
            echo("<div class=\"networkMaxHosts\">");
            echo $MaxHosts;
            echo("</div>");
            echo("</div>");
            $lineNumber = 1;
        }
    }
}
}
```

**js.js**

```
var baseURL = "https://localhost/";
var admURL = "https://localhost/admin/";
//DIV View Toggle

function toggle(div_id)
{
    var el = document.getElementById(div_id);
    if(el.style.display == 'none')
    {
        el.style.display = 'block';
    }
else
{
    el.style.display = 'none';
}
}
function togglePopBox(windowname)
{
    toggle('popBox');
    toggle('popBackground');
}
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    //Add Subnets Button
        $(".addSubnet").on('click', function()
    {
        var netID = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#popBox").load(admURL + 'addsubnet' + '?network=' + netID, setupInternalPopBoxNetworks);
    }); 

    //Kills popup
    function setupInternalPopBoxNetworks()
    {
        $("#cancelNet").on('click', function()
        {
            $("#popBox").load(baseURL + 'blank', setupInternalPopBoxNetworks);
        });
    }


    //Network Search Function
    $('#searchNetworkID').keyup(function(e){
        $("#networkBox").load(baseURL + 'network.search' + '?networkSearch=' + $('#searchNetworkID').val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it figured out. I thought I was binding to a static element, but I ended up binding to an element a bit higher up in my page structure - that coupled with some modifications to my js.js file I resolved the issue. Here's what my working js file looks like.

**js.js**

```
var baseURL = "https://localhost/";
var admURL = "https://localhost/admin/";
//DIV View Toggle

function toggle(div_id)
{
    var el = document.getElementById(div_id);
    if(el.style.display == 'none')
    {
        el.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else
    {
        el.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
function togglePopBox(windowname)
{
    toggle('popBox');
    toggle('popBackground');
}    
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //Add Networks Button
    $("#addNet").on('click', function()
    {
        $("#popBox").load(admURL + 'addnetwork', togglePopBox);
    });

    //Kills popup
    $("#popBox").on('click', '#cancelNet', function()
    {
        $("#popBox").load(baseURL + 'blank', togglePopBox);
    });

    //Network Search Function
    $('#superDuperBox').on('keyup', '#searchNetworkID', function(){
        $("#networkBox").load(baseURL + 'network.search' + '?networkSearch=' + $('#searchNetworkID').val(), null, null);
    });

    //Add Subnets Button
    $('#superDuperBox').on('click', '.addSubnet', function()
    {
        var netID = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#popBox").load(admURL + 'addsubnet' + '?network=' + netID, togglePopBox);
    });

    //View Subnets Button
    $('#superDuperBox').on('click', '.viewSubnet', function()
    {
        var netID = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#subnetBox").load(baseURL + 'viewsubnet' + '?network=' + netID);
    });

    //Subnet Search
    $('#superDuperBox').on('keyup', '#searchSubnetID',function(){
        $("#subnetBox").load(baseURL + 'subnet.search' + '?subnetSearch=' + $('#searchSubnetID').val());
    });

});
```